# How to echo a string inside a category in a ini file with quotes

Tags: text-processing, text-formatting

I have an ini file like for example

```
[Admin Prefixes]
# Here you can add custom prefixes to specific players or flags that are shown when using $admin_prefix$.
# Syntax: "type" "info" "prefix" "[expiration date]"

#"name" "OciXCrom" "[Timed Prefix]" "31.12.2030"
#"name" "OciXCrom" "[Scripter]"
#"steam" "STEAM_0:0:50153248" "[CM Creator]"
#"ip" "127.0.0.1" "[BOT]"
#"flag" "l" "[Head Admin]"
#"flag" "d" "[Server Admin]"
#"flag" "e" "[Test Admin]"
#"flag" "mnp" "[Premium]"
#"flag" "b" "[VIP]"
"flag" "s" "&x06]~Moderator~["
"flag" "r" "&x07]~ADMIN~["
"flag" "d" "&x06]~ADMIN~["
"flag" "f" "&x04]~ADMIN~["



[Chat Colors]
# Here you can add different chat colors to specific players or flags that are shown when using $chat_color$.
# Syntax: "type" "info" "chat color" "[expiration date]"

"flag" "s" "&x07"
"flag" "r" "&x07"
"flag" "d" "&x06"
"flag" "f" "&x01"
"flag" "" "&x01"


[Name Customization]
# Here you can modify the name shown for certain players when using $custom_name$.
# Syntax: "type" "info" "custom name" "[expiration date]"

"name" "OciXCrom" "&x03Oci&x04XC&x03rom"
```

Like for example I want to insert an entry `"steam" "STEAM_0:0:50153248" "[CM Creator]"` into **[Admin Prefixes]** section

How can it be done ? As I want to make a bash script to automate this process

I am new to linux, can someone please help me on this :)

Comment: What have you try so far?

Comment: I searched on google but couldn't find anything relevant. I just know the simple echo cmd

Comment: This data structure is called [TOML](https://toml.io/en/) … So you might want to consider looking into  [toml-cli](https://github.com/gnprice/toml-cli)

Answer (score 1):

Echo is probably not the best tool for this. Establish where you want to insert the new line and then use the append option of sed. For example to append to the end of your file:

```
sed '$a "steam" "STEAM_0:0:50153248" "[CM Creator]"' your_ini_file
```

To append after line 15, replace $ by 15, or to append after a line that has a unique patter, replace $ by /PATTERN/

Comment: I didn't notice "To append after a line that has a unique patter, replace $ by /PATTERN/" ... +1

Comment: Pattern can be anything, we need to just push the line under that section before another section

Comment: @ph3ro The pattern could be the name of that section … e.g. `sed '/\[Admin Prefixes\]/a \"steam" "STEAM_0:0:50153248" "[CM Creator]"' file`

Comment: @Raffa I expect the OP would not want the new text added between the `[Admin Prefixes]` and `# Here you can add...` lines but instead, probably, at the end of the block of text before the next section (`[Chat Colors]`).

Answer (score 1):

Using any awk you could just append the new text after the last non-empty line in the target section:

```
$ cat tst.awk
/^\[/ { prt() }
{ rec[++numLines] = $0 }
NF { lastPopulated = numLines }
END { prt() }

function prt(   i) {
    for ( i=1; i<=lastPopulated; i++ ) {
        print rec[i]
    }
    if ( rec[1] == tgtSect ) {
        print newText
    }
    for ( ; i<=numLines; i++ ) {
        print rec[i]
    }
    numLines = 0
}
```

```
$ awk -v tgtSect='[Admin Prefixes]' -v newText='"steam" "STEAM_0:0:50153248" "[CM Creator]"' -f tst.awk file
[Admin Prefixes]
# Here you can add custom prefixes to specific players or flags that are shown when using $admin_prefix$.
# Syntax: "type" "info" "prefix" "[expiration date]"

#"name" "OciXCrom" "[Timed Prefix]" "31.12.2030"
#"name" "OciXCrom" "[Scripter]"
#"steam" "STEAM_0:0:50153248" "[CM Creator]"
#"ip" "127.0.0.1" "[BOT]"
#"flag" "l" "[Head Admin]"
#"flag" "d" "[Server Admin]"
#"flag" "e" "[Test Admin]"
#"flag" "mnp" "[Premium]"
#"flag" "b" "[VIP]"
"flag" "s" "&x06]~Moderator~["
"flag" "r" "&x07]~ADMIN~["
"flag" "d" "&x06]~ADMIN~["
"flag" "f" "&x04]~ADMIN~["
"steam" "STEAM_0:0:50153248" "[CM Creator]"



[Chat Colors]
# Here you can add different chat colors to specific players or flags that are shown when using $chat_color$.
# Syntax: "type" "info" "chat color" "[expiration date]"

"flag" "s" "&x07"
"flag" "r" "&x07"
"flag" "d" "&x06"
"flag" "f" "&x01"
"flag" "" "&x01"


[Name Customization]
# Here you can modify the name shown for certain players when using $custom_name$.
# Syntax: "type" "info" "custom name" "[expiration date]"

"name" "OciXCrom" "&x03Oci&x04XC&x03rom"
```

or if, as in your case, the new text already exists commented out in your input file, you could just uncomment it (would still add it if not present):

```
$ cat tst.awk
/^\[/ { prt() }
{ rec[++numLines] = $0 }
NF { lastPopulated = numLines }
END { prt() }

function prt(   i,text) {
    for ( i=1; i<=lastPopulated; i++ ) {
        if ( rec[1] == tgtSect )  {
            text = rec[i]
            sub(/^[[:space:]]*#[[:space:]]*/,"",text)
            if ( text == newText ) {
                rec[i] = newText
                tgtSect = ""
            }
        }
        print rec[i]
    }
    if ( rec[1] == tgtSect ) {
        print newText
    }
    for ( ; i<=numLines; i++ ) {
        print rec[i]
    }
    numLines = 0
}
```

```
$ awk -v tgtSect='[Admin Prefixes]' -v newText='"steam" "STEAM_0:0:50153248" "[CM Creator]"' -f tst.awk file
[Admin Prefixes]
# Here you can add custom prefixes to specific players or flags that are shown when using $admin_prefix$.
# Syntax: "type" "info" "prefix" "[expiration date]"

#"name" "OciXCrom" "[Timed Prefix]" "31.12.2030"
#"name" "OciXCrom" "[Scripter]"
"steam" "STEAM_0:0:50153248" "[CM Creator]"
#"ip" "127.0.0.1" "[BOT]"
#"flag" "l" "[Head Admin]"
#"flag" "d" "[Server Admin]"
#"flag" "e" "[Test Admin]"
#"flag" "mnp" "[Premium]"
#"flag" "b" "[VIP]"
"flag" "s" "&x06]~Moderator~["
"flag" "r" "&x07]~ADMIN~["
"flag" "d" "&x06]~ADMIN~["
"flag" "f" "&x04]~ADMIN~["



[Chat Colors]
# Here you can add different chat colors to specific players or flags that are shown when using $chat_color$.
# Syntax: "type" "info" "chat color" "[expiration date]"

"flag" "s" "&x07"
"flag" "r" "&x07"
"flag" "d" "&x06"
"flag" "f" "&x01"
"flag" "" "&x01"


[Name Customization]
# Here you can modify the name shown for certain players when using $custom_name$.
# Syntax: "type" "info" "custom name" "[expiration date]"

"name" "OciXCrom" "&x03Oci&x04XC&x03rom"
```

Note the existing `"steam"...` line early in the target block has now been uncommented rather than an additional line added to the end of the block.

That second script would also mean the new text would not be added again if it was already present uncommented in the input file (e.g. if you had ran this script on it previously).

the second script relies on your awk supporting POSIX character classes, if that's not the case just change each `[[:space:]]` to `[ \t]`.